# retrieve lines from a text file in python and

Tags: python, file

I have this txt file in Python and I want to extract the DeviceID and the Size into 2 separate variables. The file looks something like this:

```
DeviceID   Size
F:         7790379008
```

I used this code:

```
with open('Disk.txt', 'rb') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)

f.close()
```

But I keep getting some coded output:

[image]

Comment: you are reading file in binary mode try 'r' instead of 'rb'

Comment: Also, make sure you specify the correct text encoding for the file. It looks like this file is encoded in UTF-16.

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of text.

Comment: another small addition: you don't need `f.close()` if you use the `with` context manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `r` in place of `rb` since your file is a text file.

```
with open('Disk.txt', 'r') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    for line in contents[1:] :
        line = line.replace(' ','')
        line = line.split(':')
        DeviceID = line[0]+':'
        Size = int(line[1])
        print(DeviceID,Size)
```

Comment: Thank you but your code kept giving me this error can you help me please ? :             
  Size = line[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Can you share the input data as text in your question

Comment: `line in contents[1:]` is only required if you have headings, else use `line in contents`

Comment: Thank you Roshin this is the input data: DeviceID  Size         
                                                              H:        15673835520

Comment: The deviceID and the size are headings i want to retrieve the values in two seperate variables thank you in advance appreciate your help !